# How to set tx_extbase_type in fe_users with sf_register 9.4.1 and TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm using sf_register for frontend user registration. As I need to query the fe_user respository in my extension I have to set tx_extbase_type to Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser.

I set

```
TCAdefaults.fe_users.tx_extbase_type = Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser
```

so that if I add a feuser in the backend tx_extbase_type is set as expected.
But if the feuser ist created in the frontend, the value is set to 0.
I changed the field definition in the database to default to Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser.

Is there a solution to achive the goal?

Thank you

Christian

Answer (score 0):

When created in the frontend through an Extbase action TSConfig TCAdefaults are not respected.

The only way to my knowledge to set defaults would be in the controller (probably here https://github.com/evoWeb/sf_register/blob/develop/Classes/Controller/FeuserCreateController.php#L89) or as a default value in the Extbase model.